# Is more granular versioning in a monorepo with a container possible?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monorepo, lerna

My team has a monorepo written with React, built with Webpack, and managed with Lerna.

Currently, our monorepo contains a package for each screen in the app, plus a "container" package that is basically a router that lazily serves each screen. The container package has all the screens' packages as dependencies.

The problem we keep running into is that, by Lerna's convention, that container package always contains the latest version of each screen. However, we aren't always ready to take the latest version of each screen to production.

I think we need more granular control over the versions of each screen/dependency.

What would be a better way to handle this? Module Federation? peerDependencies? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is right for your use case as you may need to stick with a monorepo for some reason, but we have a similar situation where our frontend needs to pull in different screens from different custom packages. The way we handle this is by structuring each screen or set of screens as its own `npm` package in its own directory (this can be as simple as just creating a corresponding `package.json`), publishing it to its own private Git repository, and then installing it in the container package via `npm` as you would any other module (you will need to create a Git token or set up SSH access if you use a private repo).

The added benefit of this is that you can use Git release tags to mark commits with versions (we wrote our own utility that manages this process for us automatically using Git hooks to make this easier), and then you can use the same semver ranges that you would with a regular `npm` package to control which version you install.

For example, one of your dependencies in your container `package.json` could look something like this: `"my-package": "git+ssh://git@github.<company>.com:<org or user>/<repo>#semver:^1.0.0` and on the GitHub side, you would mark your commit with the tag `v1.0.0`. Now just import your components and render as needed

Answer (score 1):

> However, we aren't always ready to take the latest version of each screen to production.

If this is a situation that occurs very often, then maybe a monorepo is not the best way to structure the project code? A monorepo is ideal to accommodate the opposite case, where you want to be sure that everything integrates together before merging.

This is often the fastest way to develop, as you don't end up pushing an indeterminate amount of integration work into the future. If you (or someone else) have to come back to it later you'll lose time context switching. Getting it out of the way is more efficient and a monorepo makes that as easy as it can be.

If you need to support older versions of code for some time because it's depended on by code you can't change (yet), you can sometimes just **store multiple versions on your main branch**. React is a great example, take a look at all the `.new.js` and `.old.js` files:

https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/e099e1dc0eeaef7ef1cb2b6430533b2e962f80a9/packages/react-reconciler/src *Current last commit on `main`*

Sure, it creates some "duplication", but if you need to have both versions working and maintained for the foreseeable future, it's much easier if they're both there all the time. Everybody gets to pull it, nobody can miss it because they didn't check out some tag/branch.

You shouldn't overdo this either, of course. Ideally it's a temporary measure you can remove once no code depends on the old version anymore.